# Polynomial with real coefficient which has root $\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to find a polynomial with real coefficients with a root of $\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}$ ?

Comment: with _real_ coefficients? $x-(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})$...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Why not make it an answer

Answer (score 2):

If all you want are "*real* coefficients", then $x-(\sqrt 5 + \sqrt 7) =0$ will suffice. Just a simple linear polynomial.

But this sort of question usually involves finding polynomials with *integer* coefficients.

The usual way is to start by writing $x = \sqrt 5 + \sqrt 7$

Then square both sides. Use the binomial theorem to expand the RHS.

You'll have $x^2 = m +2\sqrt n$, where $m, n$ are integers you can find (you have to do this work yourself).

Then rearrange to $x^2 - m = 2\sqrt n$ (keep the surd terms on one side in every step) and square again.

You'll end up with a quartic (degree 4) with integer coefficients, one root of which is guaranteed to be the surd you started with.

Answer (score 0):

Per your question with a "real coefficient", all you have to do is take $P(x) = x - \sqrt{5}-\sqrt{7}$ and it does it. But if you want a polynomial with "integer" coefficients, then you need a bit more work. You can take advantage of "conjugate" and form your answer quickly as follows: Take $P(x) = (x-\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{7})(x-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})((x+\sqrt{5})^2-7)$. You need not simplify this and still know it's an integer coefficient polynomial with a root $x = \sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean "rational" or "integer" instead of real.

Let $x=\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}$. Then $x^2=5+7+2\sqrt{35}=12+2\sqrt{35}$. Generally, $a+\sqrt{b}$ and $a-\sqrt{b}$ form the roots of a quadratic when $\sqrt{b}\notin\mathbb{Q}$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. Applying that here, the sum of the roots of the polynomial with roots $12+2\sqrt{35}$ and $12-2\sqrt{35}$ is $24$. The product of the roots is $12^2-4*35=4$. Therefore $12+2\sqrt{35}$ is one of the roots of $z^2-24z+4=0$ (by Vieta's). This implies that $x^2$ is a root of $z^2-24z+4=0$, and consequently $\boxed{x^4-24x^2+4=0}$.

Check for yourself that this works. In fact, this is the *minimal polynomial* of $\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}$.